# C# - Pass an object to constructor which is null at the moment but will be created later

Tags: c#, null

I would like to pass an object, which is null at the moment, but will be created later, to a constructor of another object, like this:

```
State state1 = null;
State state2 = null;
State state3 = null;

state3 = new State(new char[] { '1', '0', '@' },
             new Transition[] { new Transition(ref state3, '1', Movement.H),
                        new Transition(ref state3, '0', Movement.H),
                        new Transition(ref state3,'@', Movement.H)}, true);

state1 = new State(new char[] { '1', '0', '@' },
new Transition[] { new Transition(ref state1, '1', Movement.R),
                        new Transition(ref state1, '0', Movement.R),
                        new Transition(ref state2,'@', Movement.L)}, false);

state2 = new State(new char[] { '1', '0', '@' },
             new Transition[] { new Transition(ref state2, '0', Movement.L),
                        new Transition(ref state3, '1', Movement.L),
                        new Transition(ref state3,'1', Movement.L)}, false);
```

The `State`Objects are stored inside a `Tuple<>` like this:

```
public Transition(ref State state, char exchangeChar, Movement move)
{
    transition = new Tuple<State, char, Movement>(state, exchangeChar, move);
}
```

Even though i pass it explicitly as `reference`, the `State` object is still null. Why is that?

Comment: This is certainly a code smell... I would refactor to avoid doing this. Consider using the Lazy<> wrapper, or creating a factory for your objects instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you 'de-ref' it in the call to `new Tuple<State, char, Movement>`.

You should make a wrapper class where you wrap the state parameter in. That can be a generic class to make thing easy for you. You need to pass along that wrapper as much as possible.

A good second option is to use `Func<State>`, which will 'calculate' the value each time it is called.

Another option is to use `Lazy`, which will take the value just once, which might be triggered at the wrong time for you and unexpected sometimes.

Comment: Or use `System.Nullable<T>` maybe?

Comment: No, that doesn't help anything in this case. It is a struct so it is copied once passed into a method. @Lovy

Comment: Another option is to defer evaluation -- change the parameter from `ref State` to `Func<State>` and call it with `() => state1`

Comment: I am amazed that there is something for that problem in the .NET library, thanks a lot, `Lazy` works perfectly!